# Update Nested JSON Structure in DynomoDB in Python

Tags: python, json, amazon-dynamodb

I'm having trouble figuring out how to update a nested JSON table with DynamoDB and Python.

I was able to get something simple working, but now I need to have a deeper nested structure in my database schema and I can't figure it out.

Could someone show me how I would update the "alarm_log" list when the "phone" attribute value matches (ex. "+14086272826")?  The key for the table is "twilio_number".

```
{
  "twilio_number": "+18342388712",
  "user_numbers": [
    {
      "alarm_log": [{
                        "date_sent": "10-20-19",
                        "alarm_type": "234",
                        "alarm_sms_sid": "SID32342352",
                        "acknowledged": "yes"
                    }],
      "phone": "+14086272826"
    },
    {
      "alarm_log": [{
                        "date_sent": "10-21-19",
                        "alarm_type": "534",
                        "alarm_sms_sid": "SID32342342352",
                        "acknowledged": "yes"
                    }],
      "phone": "+14082064826"
    }
  ]
}
```

On a simple version of the table I used this code to update (appending new data to the list) but with the new schema I can't figure out how to update the correct "alarm_log" that matches the correct "phone" value.

```
UpdateExpression='SET alarm_log = list_append(alarm_log, :data_obj)',
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ":data_obj": [
                        {
                            'date_sent': date_sent,
                            'alarm_type': alarm_type,
                            'alarm_sms_sid': alarm_sms_sid,
                            'acknowledged': 'yes'
                        }
                ]
            }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to update multiple records in one request, that is not supported in 
dynamo.

If you wish to add multiple records in one request, use [batchwriteItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) which can add upto 25 items.

If you want to update an existing record use [updateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html). As in your case, you would have to update items seperately.

As you have mentioned key for table is "twilio_number".
If this is the only key for the table, all the request to update alarm_log would over write an entry and you would have only one item after all the updates.

You can create a range/sort key based on phone number 
(Composite primary key with partition key {twilio_number} + sort_key {phone_number}).
While updating provide these keys to update item request.

Make sure twilio_number + phone_number is unique for an item else it would overwrite an existing entry.